# JQuery PopUp Postion Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

jQuery PopUp positioning not working. **Pop Border and content seperated.**

Tried following code

```
    newDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
    $(newDiv).addClass("popup hide-scrol");
    newDiv.dialog({
        autoOpen: false, modal: true, show: "blind", hide: "blind" 
    });
    newDiv.html(response);
    newDiv.dialog("option", "width", $(".render-body").width() * 0.5);
    newDiv.position({
                     my: "center",
                     at: "left",
                     of: ".container"
                     });
```

OutPut

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
newDiv.dialog("option").position({
   my: 'center',
   at: 'left',
   of: "#targetElement"
});
```

and Quoting the api doc of [JQuery Ui](https://api.jqueryui.com/position/)

> **of** (default: null)
>
> > Type: Selector or Element or jQuery or Event
> >     Which element to position against. If you provide a selector or jQuery object, the first matching element will be used. If you provide an event object, the pageX and pageY properties will be used. Example: "#top-menu"